# Eliminate weird characters in Json string when calling the API by using C#?

Tags: c#, json, tags, json.net

I am developing an website for my company and in there I want to tag skills to specific people. So the programming tags that shows in stackoverflow is a valuable source. SO I want to get the tag db of the stackoverflow.

I found an API for that.

[API for the TAGS](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?page=400&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow)

So what I am trying to do is read this json string and forloop through the pages to get the tags and save them in a DB.

```
private static void ReadJson()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        //DefaultRequestHeader to Json
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        //Create an instance of HttpResponse & invoke the service asynchronously
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?page=400&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow").Result;

        //Http Status code 200
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Read response content result into string variable
            string JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            //Deserialize the string(JSON) object
            var jObj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSON);

            //access items from anonymous (Json object) type and add to the list
            var result = jObj["items"].Select(item => new
            {
                name = item["name"]

            }).ToList();

            //output the data || NOTE: **NSERT into database table**
            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.name);
            }
        }
    }
```

So at `string JSON = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;`

method it shows some weired charachters ( triangels and shapes ) because of that process is stopping there.

```
0\0\0�Z�n�8\f��<�E/S��,-�cYtuI�\f�ߗf\a�g�
```

What I am doing wrong here?

If there any way to make this happen please contribute your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're getting is a compressed response. So instead of reading it as a string, read it as a byte[], decompress it and you'll find your JSON string.

```
static async void DoStuff()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags?page=400&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow");
    var decompressedJson = new StreamReader(new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(bytes), CompressionMode.Decompress)).ReadToEnd();

    // decompressedJson will now contain '{"items":[{"has_synonyms":false, .....'
    // Continue with deserialization of JSON
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Task t = new Task(DoStuff);
    t.Start();

    Console.WriteLine("Doing stuff");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

}

You can continue with the deserialization from there. Keep in mind that the API will throw an error when you're sending too many requests.

Comment: That is because it's an async operation. I've added a Task framework to show it working. Keep in mind that the StackExchange API will throw a throttling error if you spam it so you're better off saving the string to notepad or something while you're developing your app.